# React Native: Read CSV File

Tags: json, react-native, csv

I want to upload records of students of a university using CSV file. I have upload the CSV file using `react-native-document-picker`. Now the problem is that, I am unable to read CSV Data. My main motive is to upload CSV data to firebase. How to read CSV data in React Native or covert CSVtoJSON?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert CSV to JSON before pushing data to Firebase. There're numerous utility libraries for that. You can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson